# Can't restore image to USB stick

Tags: restore, disk-utility, usb

When I try to restore, I get message:

```
Could not validate source - Operation not supported
```

haven't seen anything like this on the web

Comment: Could you elaborate on how are you doing it?

Answer (score 1):

As the message says, it can't validate the source, meaning that either you are poiting to a wrong file (such as an alias, por instance) or the image you are trying to restore is corrupted.

Comment: Indeed, the USB stick is irrelevant to this question, the problem lies squarely with the media/image you are choosing to restore from